# Sequelize Unable to use transaction inside array.map Node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Iam using sequelize with async/await in node js.When I try to use the transaction inside the array.map,it throws some error `ReferenceError: t is not defined`.Following is my code

```
    try
{
    const newExitEntry = {
        given_by:user_id,
        received_by:received_by,
        created_by:user_id,
        description:description,
        status:true
    };
    let stock_inventory_result;
    const t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
    let result = await ExitEntry.create(newExitEntry,{transaction:t});
    const newExitEntryItems = await Promise.all(item_array.map(async (data) => {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('product_name')) { 
        try{

            stock_inventory_result = await  StockInventory.update({quantity:db.sequelize.literal(`"quantitys"-`+data.quantity)},{where:{id:data.product_name},transaction:t});
            console.log("heree");
        }   
        catch(error){

            console.log(error);
            await t.rollback(); 
            //throw new Error("Failed to insert stock inventory");
            return  res.status(constants.response_codes.error).json(responses.errorMsg('create_exit_entry_failed', lang.error.create_exit_entry_failed));
        }
        return Object.assign(   
        {},
        {
        inventory_id:data.product_name,
        exit_entry_id:result.id,
        quantity:data.quantity,
        status : true,
        })
        }
    }));
    console.log("hi");
    result = await ExitEntryItems.bulkCreate(newExitEntryItems,{transaction:t});
    await t.commit();
   if(result)
        return res.status(constants.response_codes.success).json(responses.successMsg('create_exit_entry_success',lang.success.create_exit_entry_success));
    else
        return  res.status(constants.response_codes.error).json(responses.errorMsg('create_exit_entry_failed', lang.error.create_exit_entry_failed));

}
```

The transaction variable is const t = await db.sequelize.transaction();
But inside the map() function when I try to rollback the transaction,this error occurs.

Comment: what is the output of this console.log(error); before await t.rollback();?

Comment: what is the output of db.sequelize.transaction() function?

Comment: The scope of the variable const t =await db.sequelize.transaction(); is only inside try catch statement.So I just declare the variable t before the  try statement.Thus resolved the error.